# proving L = {$a^{100}yy^r : \forall y \in$ {a,b}*} is not regular

Tags: regular-languages

I need to prove that L = {$a^{100}yy^r : \forall y \in$ {a,b}*} is not regular. i have tried using pumping lemma but couldn't get far with it. Any help in where i should go with it?

Comment: So, what is your question? What did you try (in details)? Where did you get stuck? These should be included in the the OP.

Comment: so far i tried using the adversary pumping lemma, let adv pick n and we pick z = $a^{100}a^nba^n(a^nba^n)^r$ im not sure if my setup is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove that a language is not regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular)

Comment: Get rid of the initial part $a^{100}$ by taking an appropriate quotient.